# Remove following duplicates in a tuple

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I have tuples of arbitrary size. This is an example:

```
ax = ('0','1','1','1','2','2','2','3')
```

For x axis labeling I want to convert this tuple to:

```
ax = ('0','1','','','2','','','3')
```

So duplicates should be erased while the tuple size should stay the same. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Just a small thing: I believe that is a tuple, and not a list. There are some subtle differences, but it may not matter for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [12]: seen = set()

In [13]: [x if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else '' for x in ax]
Out[13]: ['0', '1', '', '', '2', '', '', '3']
```

This is a slightly modified version of a uniquifier suggested by [Dave Kirby, here](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark).

---

`seen.add(x)` adds `x` to the set `seen`. The `seen.add` method returns `None`. So
in a boolean context, (since `bool(None)` is `False`), `not seen.add(x)` is always `True`. Therefore the condition

```
x not in seen and not seen.add(x)
```

has a boolean value equal to

```
x not in seen and True
```

which is equivalent to

```
x not in seen
```

So the conditional expression

```
x if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else ''
```

returns `x` if `x` is not already in `seen` and returns `''` if `x` is already in `seen` (and `x` then gets added to `seen`). If `x not in seen` is `False` (that is, if `x` is already in `seen`) then `seen.add(x)` is not called because Python's `and` short-circuits -- any expression of the form `False and something` is automatically `False` without one having to evaluate `something`.

---

This could also be written, not as succinctly, but without the complexity, as

```
def replace_dupes(ax):
    result = []
    seen = set()
    for x in ax:
        if x in seen:
            result.append('')
        else:
            seen.add(x)
            result.append(x)
    return result

ax = ('0','1','1','1','2','2','2','3')
print(replace_dupes(ax))
# ['0', '1', '', '', '2', '', '', '3']
```

Comment: what `not seen.add(x)` does?

Comment: `The add function returns None`, is this for set only?

Comment: Python methods from the standard library generally follow the [Command-query separation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). Methods that modify the object (i.e. commands) return `None`, while methods that query the object return a value and have no side-effects. `list.sort` and `dict.update` are also examples of methods that modify the object and return `None`.

Comment: So it's not there to check a condition but to add the item to the set right? Assuming to hack some list comprehension limitations?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solves my problem :)

Comment: @ayhan: yes, afraid so. It's there in the expression merely for its side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for adjacent duplicates, then you could make use of Python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

ax = ['0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3']
ax_output = []

for k, g in groupby(ax):
    ax_output.extend([k] + [''] * (len(list(g))-1))

print ax_output
```

This would give you the following list:

```
['0', '1', '', '', '2', '', '', '3']
```